Have Solr also log when Lucene performs a segment merge
I'm looking for a way to know when a segment merge happens in Solr.
My current approach is via the logs, but JMX would also be fine if that's possible.
I've tried adding the following to the log4j2.xml:
        <RollingFile
                name="RollingFileLucene"
                fileName="${sys:solr.log.dir}/lucene.log"
                filePattern="${sys:solr.log.dir}/lucene.log.%i" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>
                    %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p (%t) [%X{collection} %X{shard} %X{replica} %X{core}] %c{1.} %m%n
                </Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="32 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
...
        <Logger name="org.apache.lucene" level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileLucene"/>
        </Logger>

The file lucene.log is created, but stays empty.
Am I missing something? Or does something completely different have be done?
